# What is a formal parameter list in execution context of javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to know what is a formal parameter list in Execution context of javascript. Say for example i have a function like this

```
function test(a, b, c) {
    var d, e;
}
```

When this function is activated what will be the formal parameter list? Will it be just a,b and c or d and e will also be there?

Comment: Assuming that you're using the correct terms, see http://es5.github.com/#A.5 (definition of formal parameter list) and http://es5.github.com/#x10.6 (definition of `Arguments` object)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formal parameters are values provided as input to the function, so in your case formal parameters are only: a, b and c.

Answer (score 0):

a, b, and c are parameters, d and e are just local variables.

What problem are you trying to solve with this?

Comment: I want to know what happens in the execution context and what will be the contents of the formal parameter list in the activation object

Comment: The formal parameters will contain the values that were passed as arguments to the function. JavaScript is object-oriented, so these values are references to the caller's objects, not copies -- modifying properties of the variables will modify the original objects.